# Anything wrong with this Do While Loop, it displays the results of multiple functions unless the one choice that the While states

Tags: java

The do while loop shows the results of all the functions when choice = 1 or 2, but it works fine when choice =3, ive tried changing the while condition but it still doesnt works, any suggestions??

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    staffMenuScreen();
}

public static void staffMenuScreen()
{
    int choice;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    do
    {
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.println("| 1.Login (Existing user)     |");
        System.out.println("| 2.Register (New user)       |");
        System.out.println("| 3.Back                      |");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
        choice = s.nextInt();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                loginScreen();
            case 2:
                registerScreen();
            default:
                System.out.println("Thank you");
        }
    }while(choice!=3);
}    

public static void loginScreen()
{
    System.out.println("Login");
}

public static void registerScreen()
{

    System.out.println("Register");
}
```

Comment: put break after both function calls. Read this https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_switch.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void staffMenuScreen()
{
    int choice;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    do
    {
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.println("| 1.Login (Existing user)     |");
        System.out.println("| 2.Register (New user)       |");
        System.out.println("| 3.Back                      |");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
        choice = s.nextInt();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                loginScreen();
                break;
            case 2:
                registerScreen();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Thank you");
        }
    }while(choice!=3);
}
```

Break statement is missing from your switch case. Please read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: @MelvinTanVictory if this resolves your query, accept this answer, so we can close this thread.